# Redirect error in php login system

Tags: php, redirect, authentication, error-handling, system

So i made a simple login page, but im having a problem with the index.php page. It gives me a redirect error. Im a newbie in php coding. Hopefully someone can help me with this.

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){ 
        header('Location: index.php'); 
        exit;
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
       Login Successful
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks anyway!

Comment: what is the error you get? Also, `<body` tag is not ending  correctly.

Comment: What redirect error ?

Comment: More than likely the name of the script is index.php and it is trying to infinitely redirect to itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going on the assumption that my comment above is correct.... Here is a very non-secure implementation, but it should get you started.

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    if(!isset($_SESSION['user_name'])){ 
    header('Location: login.php'); 
    exit;
    }
?>

<html>
    <body>
       Login Successful
    </body>
</html>
```

login.php:

```
<?php
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['user_name'] = "John Doe";
    header('Location: index.php'); 
?>

<html>
    <body
       Who needs passwords, eh?
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So with theese codes it redirects from login.php to index.php Am i right?

Comment: Correct. What you'd normally do is when login.php is called, it will output a login form and the form action would be login.php. On the second call it'll see data in $_POST and handle the login action and then output the redirect location header. Here's a much longer and involved tutorial: http://php.about.com/od/finishedphp1/ss/php_login_code.htm

Comment: Thanks, got it now. Just the index.php file does not show HTML content. I also added require_once function to the index.php file so you cant access it straight, but it always redirects me back to login page after i've entered the username and password. Do you know why?

Comment: what is your require_once? Also what changes have you made to your login.php?

Comment: I have not made any changes to login.php and html is working now, and the require_once is going to the login form (main_login.php) does not seem to work now, it shows me the index.php but with the loogin form ontop of it.